# Optimizing the initialization in python

Tags: python, optimization

I am looking to optimize the small code below:

```
def update_users_genre_lang_score(cursor):
    cursor.execute("select user_id,playDuration,lang,genre from sd_archive_track_clicks where playDuration > 15 and user_id!=0 and genre!=0 and lang!=0 and lang <21 and genre <24 and playDate > '2016-10-01'order by playDate desc")
    db.commit()
    numrows = int(cursor.rowcount)
    tracks_played= cursor.fetchall()

    genre_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]
    lang_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
    #initialization part
    user_genre_score = {}
    user_lang_score = {}

    for track in tracks_played:
        user_genre_score[track['user_id']]={}
        user_lang_score[track['user_id']]={}
        for genre in genre_list:
            user_genre_score[track['user_id']][genre]=0
        for lang in lang_list:
            user_lang_score[track['user_id']][lang]=0

    #initialization part end
    for track in tracks_played:
        user_genre_score[track['user_id']][track['genre']]=int(user_genre_score[track['user_id']][track['genre']]) + 1
        user_lang_score[track['user_id']][track['lang']]=int(user_lang_score[track['user_id']][track['lang']]) + 1
```

Is there any way I can optimize the initialization step?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: OK I will put it on codereview.stackexchange.com. Thanks!

Comment: It is a good practice to not keep the question alive on both platforms, so if you post it there, kindly do remove it from here.

Comment: codereview is a good place but people may jump in here also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get some speedup by creating default dicts and copying them to your records. Here is sample code with some comments...

```
def update_users_genre_lang_score(cursor):
    # you are asking for a lot of stuff but only using a little. Is this
    # stuff consumed in this function?
    cursor.execute("select user_id,playDuration,lang,genre from sd_archive_track_clicks where playDuration > 15 and user_id!=0 and genre!=0 and lang!=0 and lang <21 and genre <24 and playDate > '2016-10-01'order by playDate desc")
    # what is the commit for?
    # db.commit()
    numrows = int(cursor.rowcount)
    tracks_played= cursor.fetchall()
    #print tracks_played

    genre_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]
    genre_default = {genre:0 for genre in genre_list}
    lang_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
    lang_default = {lang:0 for lang in lang_list}

    #initialization part

    user_genre_score = {}
    user_lang_score = {}
    for track in tracks_played:
            user_id = track['user_id']
            user_genre_score[user_id]=genre_default.copy()
            user_lang_score[user_id]=lang_default.copy()

    #initialization part end

    # this seems like an expensive way to initialize to 1 instead of 0...
    # am i missing something?!
    for track in tracks_played:
        user_genre_score[track['user_id']][track['genre']] += 1
        user_lang_score[track['user_id']][track['lang']] += 1
```

**UPDATE**

You could initialize with `collections.defaultdict` so that items are generated dynamically as you touch them. This saves you from revisiting the nodes for each time user_id appears in the rows.

```
import collections

def update_users_genre_lang_score(cursor):
    cursor.execute("select user_id,playDuration,lang,genre from sd_archive_track_clicks where playDuration > 15 and user_id!=0 and genre!=0 and lang!=0 and lang <21 and genre <24 and playDate > '2016-10-01'order by playDate desc")
    # what is the commit for?
    # db.commit()
    numrows = int(cursor.rowcount)
    tracks_played= cursor.fetchall()
    #print tracks_played

    #initialization part

    # this creates a two level nested dict ending in an integer count 
    # that generates items dynamically
    user_genre_score = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(int))
    user_lang_score = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(int))

    #initialization part end

    for track in tracks_played:
            user_genre_score[track['user_id']][track['genre']] += 1
            user_lang_score[track['user_id']][track['lang']] += 1
```

**How It Works**

`defaultdict` can make your brain explode - fair warning. With `dict`, accessing a non-existent key raises `KeyError`. But with `defaultdict`, it calls an initializer you supply and creates a key for you. When you call `int()` you get a 0.

```
>>> int() 
0
```

So if we make it the initializer, you get 0 when you first access a new key

```
>>> d1 = collections.defaultdict(int)
>>> d1
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {})
>>> d1['user1']
0
>>> d1
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'user1': 0})
```

If you increment a new key, python first gets the item which does the initialization

```
>>> d1['user2'] += 1
>>> d1
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'user1': 0, 'user2': 1})
```

But you need two levels of dicts..., so have the outer one create inner `defaultdict`

```
>>> d2 = collections.defaultdict(lambda:collections.defaultdict(int))
>>> d2['user1']
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {})
>>> d2['user1']['genre1']
0
>>> d2
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7efedf493bf8>, {'user1': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'genre1': 0})})
>>> d2['user1']['genre2'] += 1
>>> d2
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7efedf493bf8>, {'user1': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'genre1': 0, 'genre2': 1})})
```

Comment: The purpose here # this seems like an expensive way to initialize to 1 instead of 0...
    # am i missing something?!
    for track in tracks_played:
        user_genre_score[track['user_id']][track['genre']] += 1
        user_lang_score[track['user_id']][track['lang']] += 1                                        is to increment the value of genre_score for each user_id. example, if a user has listened to songs of genre id 6 10 times then for user1 and genre id 6 his genre score shall be 10

Comment: oh... same user_id multiple times. I think I have an update.

Comment: Maybe the solution is to skip that pesky preload completely.

Comment: but internally the lambda function might be doing the same task as I was doing in for loops. Is this right ?

Comment: Kinda. You have the same user_id many times in the rows. In your original loop, `user_genre_score[track['user_id']]={}` is likely overwriting a user_id entry already initialized. If each user_id is seen 100 times, 99% of your initialization is thrown away. In my sample, entries are only created once ... or maybe never if the user happens not to have touched a particular genre.

Comment: You could also eliminate the too-many initializations problem by eliminating duplicate user ids: `for track in set(track['user_id'] for track in tracks_played):`.

Comment: yeah thanks.. in user_genre_score = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(int)) can you giude me how its creating dictionary inside dictionary for each user_id.. Since I thought your code may generate the keyerror but its working fine !!

Comment: Great answer. If stackoverflow would have  the feature to follow.. I would have followed you immediately :) !!

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize it like this

```
genre_list = list(range(1,24))
lang_list = list(range(1,23))
```

Comment: ... or `list(range(1,24))`. No need to covert ints to ints.

Comment: dont even need list() for that matter.

Comment: I want to optimize the for loops since user_ids will vary from 1,1000000. I mean the code below comment (initialization part) Is there any way?

Comment: Assuming this is python 3, you need list(). Otherwise you just have a generator.

Comment: guys initialization is inside for loop:    for track in tracks_played:

            user_genre_score[track['user_id']]={}
            user_lang_score[track['user_id']]={}
            for genre in genre_list:
                    user_genre_score[track['user_id']][genre]=0
            for lang in lang_list:
                    user_lang_score[track['user_id']][lang]=0