# 'long' object is not iterable

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to iterate over the below dict inside dict. user_genre_score is dict inside dict. It is created using

Edit:

```
genre_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]
lang_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

user_genre_score = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(int))
```

Edit

```
for track in tracks_played:
        user_genre_score[track['user_id']][track['genre']]=int(user_genre_score[track['user_id']][track['genre']]) + 1
        user_lang_score[track['user_id']][track['lang']]=int(user_lang_score[track['user_id']][track['lang']]) + 1
```

user_genre_score values after updation are:

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7fb1eb36e140>, {38913L: defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {10L: 1}), 38949L: defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {8L: 1, 10L: 1, 22L: 1}), 38985L: defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {8L: 1}), 19309L: defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {9L: 1, 10L: 2, 11L: 3}), 38959L: defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {11L: 1}), 19763L: defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {13L: 1}), 38708L: defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {2L: 1, 11L: 1}), 38902L: defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {3L: 1, 22L: 10}), 38905L: defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {4L: 2}), 23695L: defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {6L: 17}), 13502L: defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {5L: 1, 22L: 4})})
```

Now I am trying to iterate over user_genre_score.

```
    for k,v in user_genre_score.iteritems():
        print k
```

But getting below error:

```
'long' object is not iterable
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: why is the key of long datatype .. 13502L: defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {5L: 1, 22L: 4}) seems some issue while updating the user_genre_score. Can you recheck/post this part of your code

Comment: It gives no error to me...how are you inserting key-value pairs in your default-dict ?

Comment: Added the same, detail explanation can be found here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42968379/optimizing-the-initialization-in-python/42968752

Comment: what about trying `user_genre_score.items()`? ref:[TypeError: 'long' object is not iterable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40651482/typeerror-long-object-is-not-iterable)